# How to trigger event after i scroll a page certain amount in pixels from the top? Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop, onscroll

I am trying to trigger a video when I scroll a page 300px from the top. This works if I scroll

```
window.onscroll = function(event) {
myvideo.play();
}
```

but I would like it to play once I scroll 300px

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check `$(document).scrollTop()`

Try:

```
 $(document).bind("scroll", function(){    
    if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 300) {
       myvideo.play();
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

Because We dont want the movie to play every time they scroll a pixel beyond 300 after the video is played you can unbind the event

```
$(document).bind("scroll.myScroll", function(){    
    if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 300) {
        myvideo.play();
        $(document).unbind('.myScroll');
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7ndC/)

Comment: Using `.one()` instead of `.scroll()` would be better. Don't want the movie to play every time they scroll a pixel beyond 300.

Comment: @laaposto Thanks, Eris was right about the continues play

Comment: @Eric Thanks, Eric will try the .one()

Comment: @Zinox i upadted my answer now it fires only once

Comment: Thanks Everyone! Still a little stuck but it give me a good insight